# Transferring an html layout into a joomla template javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, joomla, joomla3.0

I created a website layout through my basic notepad editor and the code works as a standalone html page. I tried transferring it to a joomla template, but the javascript code just isn't working. It's for a menu that is mobile responsive.

Here's the javescript code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-button").click(function () {
    $(".nav-button,.primary-nav").toggleClass("open");
    });    
});
</script>
```

Is there a special way I need to format it for the joomla template?

I tried putting it in a .js file (js/main.js) that had this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-button").click(function () {
    $(".nav-button,.primary-nav").toggleClass("open");
    });    
});
```

and then putting in the index.php file (I found this code from a similar question)

```
<?php 
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die; 

$app             = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc             = JFactory::getDocument();
$user            = JFactory::getUser();
$this->language  = $doc->language;
$this->direction = $doc->direction;

//Load jQuery using Joomla's built in method
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');

// Define the template path
$template_path = 'templates/'  .$this->template;

// Le Javascript
$doc->addScript($template_path . '/js/main.js');

?>
```

It's still not working. I would prefer to use the inline javascript code anyway, but really I just want it to work. What do I need to add to the javascript code to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add your javascript using the following code:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".nav-button").click(function () {
        jQuery(".nav-button, .primary-nav").toggleClass("open");
        });    
    });
');
```

**Note:** Joomla loads jquery in noConflict mode so you have to change `$` with `jQuery` in your jquery calls.

Reference: [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: Just added one more line for jquery inclusion. Please try that too.